# How to use if condition in document.getelementbyname in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am facing problem in if condition it validates for subject and not validate for medium field. Here checkbox is coming from mysql. But it gives source like this only. Here Know the problem is with if conditional only how to overcome this?can any figure out what is the problem in my code?what I have to do here.I hope everyone understand the question.I don't understand why the second if conditional statement is not working.

```js
function check() {
  //alert('done')
  var chk = document.getElementsByName('subject[]');
  var reg = document.getElementsByName('regional[]');
  var len = chk.length;
  var regl = reg.length;
  //alert(len);
  if (len) {
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (chk[i].checked) {
        return true;
      } else {
        alert('please select the subject');
        return false;

      }
    }
  }
  if (regl) {
    for (i = 0; i < regl; i++) {
      if (reg[i].checked) {
        return true;
      } else {
        alert('please select the regional');
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
  Subject
  <input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='science'>science<br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='maths'>maths<br/>

  Medium
  <input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='Hindi'>Hindi<br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='english'>english<br/>

  <input type="submit" name="land" class="butt" value="SUBMIT" onClick="return check();">
</form>
```

Comment: You return true way too early.

Comment: how to execute further i don't know what to do can you help me.how to solve this? this is my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Because if the first condition is getting false then it will stop executing the code because you have "return".

At a time both will not be validate as per you code.

First make all the subject checked and then try, you will get the second if will be working.

Comment: NO my requirement is like this only. what is the solution for this

Comment: min 1 subject and min 1 regional is compulsory  correct?

Comment: sorry I don't understand?

Comment: what's your requirement how many minimum subject and how many minimum regional should be checked.

Comment: http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/check-checkboxes-selected-form-submit/

pelase check the link.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check() {
  var subjects = document.getElementsByName("subject[]"),
      regionals = document.getElementsByName('regional[]'),
      subjectSelected = false,
      regionalSelected = false;
  
  // check subject
  for(var i=0;i<subjects.length;i++){
    if(subjects[i].checked){subjectSelected = true;}
  }
  
  // check medium
  for(var i=0;i<regionals.length;i++){
    if(regionals[i].checked){regionalSelected = true;}
  }
  
  if(!subjectSelected || !regionalSelected){
    if(!subjectSelected){ // subject not selected
      alert("Please select a subject.");
    }else{ // medium not selected
      alert("Please select a regional.");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
  Subject
  <input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='science'>science<br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='maths'>maths<br/>

  Medium
  <input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='Hindi'>Hindi<br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='regional[]' value='english'>english<br/>

  <input type="submit" name="land" class="butt" value="SUBMIT" onClick="return check();">
</form>
```

the mistake you did very silly. whenever you will use the return key it will exit the function and won't process below or next codes. Moreover, I think you are trying to validate the form like if at least one subject and medium is selected the form is valid. Either you want to alert the user. The easy way to do that is first take two variable inside the function, one for subject another one for medium and set both of them to false, that means nothing is selected. Now run a loop and set the related variable true if the checkbox is checked, that means at least one is checked what you want. After two loops now write a if-else-then condition for below three states:
Both true -> at least one subject and medium is checked
one true, one false -> either subject or medium is not selected.
both false -> nothing selected.

if you are trying something else leave a comment and I will post the solution. besides, feel free to ask if you have further questions.

Comment: yes you are correct can write the code for this. because since morning I am doing this. this is annoying for me.

Comment: Have you finished? help me

Comment: i thought you can manage the code. just a min. i will put it.